# sql query to Add two colomn into one column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

table A has column called name which has 5 records for 4th standard students and 6 records for 5th standard students..and 8 records for 7th standard students

I want to write a query to create a new table, which will fetch from Table A only 5th and 4th standard students records (5+6)..and the content of the name column of the new table will have 5 rows data for 4th standard students and 6 row after that with 5th standard student

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, Postgres).  Also show us table structure and what you have tried so far.

Comment: MySql server i am using

Comment: OK...30% there.  Now show us the table definition or sample data, along with a query you have tried.

Comment: And no pictures please, we want formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your table has a column named NAME and say another column named STANDARD which tells you the standard of each student. So you want a query like this:

`SELECT NAME FROM MYTABLE
WHERE STANDARD in (4, 5)
ORDER BY STANDARD ASC`

This will select only those students in standard 4 or 5 (excluding anyone above or below that), and will order the rows by the standard.

You can add 

`CREATE TABLE MYNEWTABLE AS`

before the "SELECT" to have it create a new table for you.

(Apologies if this SQL does not work in all DBs - it might not be 100% pure SQL.)

Comment: I'm just not convinced that anyone benefits from such speculative answers to such miserably poor questions.